# My Laravel project is going to wamp homepage when using lsapp.test (httpd-vhosts + .hosts)

Tags: laravel, wamp

I am trying to access my Laravel project in wamp using the domain `lsapp.test`. I can access the site fine using `localhost/lsapp/public`, but when I use the above I am sent to the wamp home page.

This is on Wamp version 3.1.3 with Apache 2.4.33, PHP 7.2.4. Here is my the httpd-vhosts file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/lsapp/public/"
  ServerName lsapp.test
</VirtualHost>
```

Windows hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 lsapp.test
::1 lsapp.test
```

I have searched for a while but wasn't able to find anything that helped with this particular issue.

Comment: Look at the example provided for localhost. What is missing in your VH.

Comment: WAMPServer 3 has a link on the WAMPServer home page that sets up Virtual Hosts for you COrrectly

Comment: @RiggsFolly the example I was shown (a video) used this exact same setup and it was working fine (just replace the wamp filepath with xampp). My problem was not rebooting the server after applying changes.

Comment: Beware there are a lot more BAD tutorials out there than GOOD ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the public path as the DirectoryRoot as well. This is the format.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/lsapp/public"
    ServerName lsapp.test
    ServerAlias *.lsapp.test

    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/lsapp/public">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require local

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Edit : Restart the Apache server to take effect after setting up vhosts

Comment: Thanks dude. For anyone who may read this question in the future, this didn't work initially, for the same reason the original code didn't - you have to restart wamp (or at least Apache) for these to take effect. That was my original downfall. This change made sure it works though, thanks.

Comment: You could have use Apache 2.4 syntax as its Apache 2.4 that is being used

Comment: @D.Winning  Yes. Ill add it to the answer, Forgot to mention to restart the servers after setting up Vhosts.Cheers Mate